# Test in app purchase using sandbox environment for independent WatchOS app

Tags: in-app-purchase, apple-watch, storekit, watchos

I have implemented an in app purchase for my independent WatchOS app created using SwiftUI, however, I cannot find resources about testing the StoreKit functionality in a sandbox environment on the Apple Watch.

When I am signed in to my normal Apple ID or no Apple ID at all on the watch App Store I receive the following alert on my watch:

> Unable to Purchase App
>
> Sign in with your Apple ID from the Apple Watch app on your iPhone.

And I receive the following error:

> SKErrorDomain error 0.

Does anyone know how to use a sandbox testing account for independent Apple Watch apps? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem while testing IAP on my independent Watch app. Did you resolve your issue? If so, how?

Comment: @Mathieu did you figure it out?

Comment: @user2875404 Sadly, I didn't. I think I'd have to log in to my test account on my iPhone and repair my Apple watch so that it is synced to that account, but that seemed like too much work since it's my personal watch and not a test device. So I shelved the idea of implementing IAP for now.

Comment: I know it’s been a while. Has anyone figured this out?

Comment: did anyone figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

So, according to Apple this is a bug. It happens on a few devices and accounts its mostly random. I filed a feedback. They soon asked if it was fixed. Whatever Apple did seems to fix it for me on the latest watchOS 8 betas. there's really nothing you can do from our side.

Feedback ID: FB9485990

If it is still happening I suggest you file a bug report.

Answer (score -1):

I had a quick look on Github and found this repo which I think implements what you're after.
https://github.com/strandlie/faerd

Hope that helps.